# Limit of the Area of a function

Tags: definite-integrals, area

What do they mean in part 2) a) by saying the are limited by (C) and $y'Oy$! I did understand the area between the function and $x'Ox$ but how it is between $x'Ox$ and $y'Oy$ together?[image: ![no.27 part 2) a)]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8pTW.jpg)
Can you solve all part 2) a)?

Comment: That means $x\in[\lambda;0]$, while $y\in[0;C]$

Comment: @EzWin then it is all the area between -1 and 0?

Comment: Between $\lambda$ and 0.  -0.5 and 0 for example. That's part a). You will get some function $A(\lambda)$, and then you should take limit to get b).

Comment: Between -0.5 and 0: is the are of the small square right?

Comment: [This.](http://imgur.com/MncyPEV) $\\$ Ops typo, $\lambda=-0.5$

Comment: Ohhh... then what is the purpose of adding y'Oy!. They need only ghe area limited by x'Ox !

Comment: y'Oy is equal to $x=0$, if you're not adding it, you will integrate from $\lambda$ to $\infty$

Comment: Oww... nice one! Thankss alotttt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Area of integration: $x\in[\lambda;0], \lambda\in(-1;0)$.

Indefinite integral: $\int \frac{x^2 dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{x^3+1} + C$.

Using [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus): $\int\limits_{\lambda}^{0} \frac{x^2 dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{x^3+1}\bigg|_\lambda^0=\frac{2}{3}(1-\sqrt{\lambda^3+1})=\mathfrak{A}(\lambda) $

Taking the limit: $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to-1}\mathfrak{A}(\lambda) = \frac{2}{3}$

> Answer: a) $\mathfrak{A}(\lambda)=\frac{2}{3}(1-\sqrt{\lambda^3+1})$, b) $\frac{2}{3}$
>   [image: Plotting for b)]

Comment: Magnifincent. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

[image: my solution]
Can anyone assure my work?
I'm not very sure

Comment: It's wrong. Don't depend on it